# How to compare the similarity of same image with different size in python using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have captured the same image with three browser using below code ( Height of the image dynamically change based on content adding and removing that particular page).

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="content" and @class="active bg-forms bg-forms-light   "]')
time.sleep(2)
total_height = ele.size["height"]+100
print(total_height)
driver.set_window_size(1920, total_height)
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.get_window_size())
```

Now I want to compare these three images are same. For that I have used structural_similarity.
But due to different size I am getting error.

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as compare_ssim
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

# load the two input images
imageA = cv2.imread("Test_chrome.jpg")
imageB = cv2.imread("Test_edge.jpg")
imageC = cv2.imread("Test_fire.jpg")

print(imageA.shape)
print(imageB.shape)
print(imageC.shape)
print(imageA.size)
print(imageB.size)
print(imageC.size)
# convert the images to grayscale
grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayC = cv2.cvtColor(imageC, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(grayA.size)
print(grayB.size)
print(grayC.size)
# compute the Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) between the two
# images, ensuring that the difference image is returned
(scoreaandb, diffaandb) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, full=True)
diffaandb = (diffaandb * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIMaandb: {}".format(scoreaandb))
(scorebandc, diffbandc) = compare_ssim(grayB, grayC, full=True)
diffbandc = (diffbandc * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIMbandc: {}".format(scorebandc))
(scoreaandc, diffaandc) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayC, full=True)
diffaandc = (diffaandc * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIMaandc: {}".format(scoreaandc))
```

Output:

```
(5956, 1920, 3)
(7306, 1920, 3)
(5994, 1908, 3)
34306560
42082560
34309656
11435520
14027520
11436552
```

I have used CV2.Resized the image as below

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as compare_ssim
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

# load the two input images
imageA = cv2.imread("Test_Chrome.jpg")
imageB = cv2.imread("Test_edge.jpg")
imageC = cv2.imread("Test_fire.jpg")

print(imageA.shape)
print(imageB.shape)
print(imageC.shape)
print(imageA.size)
print(imageB.size)
print(imageC.size)

Resized_ImageB = cv2.resize(imageB,(imageA.shape[1],imageA.shape[0]))
Resized_ImageC = cv2.resize(imageC,(imageA.shape[1],imageA.shape[0]))
# convert the images to grayscale
grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayB = cv2.cvtColor(Resized_ImageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayC = cv2.cvtColor(Resized_ImageC, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(grayA.size)
print(grayB.size)
print(grayC.size)
# compute the Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) between the two
# images, ensuring that the difference image is returned
(scoreaandb, diffaandb) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, full=True)
diffaandb = (diffaandb * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIMaandb: {}".format(scoreaandb))
(scorebandc, diffbandc) = compare_ssim(grayB, grayC, full=True)
diffbandc = (diffbandc * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIMbandc: {}".format(scorebandc))
(scoreaandc, diffaandc) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayC, full=True)
diffaandc = (diffaandc * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIMaandc: {}".format(scoreaandc))
```

I tried with imagehash also

```
import imagehash
hash0 = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open('planoverview_Chrome.jpg')) 
hash1 = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open('planoverview_Chromemodified.jpg')) 
cutoff = 1  # maximum bits that could be different between the hashes. 
print(hash0)
print(hash1)
if hash0 - hash1 < cutoff:
  print('images are similar')
else:
  print('images are not similar')
```

O/P:

```
   0307070307ffffff
    0307070307ffffff
    images are similar
```

Reporting both image are same.

Question:

I have used set (driver.set_window_size(1920, 6080))- before saving the screen short & compared the similarity and it's working fine for Egde & Chrome. But the problem here is when the content of the page grow the image is not capturing as expected.

Later  I resize before converting as Grey scale and compared the three images. But SIMM is not detecting the minor changes either report all are same or the image is completely different.

Is there any effective I can compare different size image in python using some lib & tell all are same or differnet?

Comment: Hi, it will be easy to assist you if you can provide the 3 images. what do you mean by "when the content of the page grow the image is not capturing as expected"  ? please explain it with image.

Comment: opencv-contrib has an img_hash module for this

Comment: Isn't it that the SIMM score is not sensitive enough for your purposes ?

Comment: @Prashant Maurya
May be consider Table Data /any wiki page - When Edit happen the Height will dynamically update.

Comment: @Yves Daoust
SIMM we can use for same size image. If we resize the image and convert as Grey scale and pass to SIMM not detecting the minor changes or reporting enter image is different

Comment: @Prashant Maurya  example http://webdatacommons.org/webtables/

Comment: Isn't it that the SIMM score is not sensitive enough for your purposes ?

Comment: Yes. It's not detecting the changes

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use normalized cross-correlation. If the content of the different images is the same, you need to resize the images first to have the same dimensions. OpenCV offers

[`void  cv::matchTemplate (InputArray image, InputArray templ, OutputArray result, int method, InputArray mask=noArray())`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#gga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695da5be00b45a4d99b5e42625b4400bfde65)

As `method` I suggest to use `cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED`.

Comment: Hi, Could you please help How to use in python?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @thangaraj1980 You can find an example here: [https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)
They try to locate the position of a subimage in the original image. However, using the same resolution for both images, you can use the maximum (probably upper left corner) to evaluate the similarity of both images.